# Is it possible to use old home folder after encryption?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk-formatting

My company wants me to format my computer and do disk encryption however I have tons of customizations on my pc so I don't want to lose them. I thought I can copy my home folder into external disk and do the encryption stuff and after that copy back the files. Is this possible after encryption? I mean overriding a fresly installed home folder with the old one will cause any problems? Or is there better way to handle this?

[UPDATED] I will be installing Ubuntu 22.04 jammy (LTS) and doing full-disk encryption while formatting.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux/Windows are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Yes you can, you can even non-destructively re-install onto an older Ubuntu system with *encrypted home* directory and not lose your data too (*Ubuntu used to offer home directory encryption long ago.. I used it one some systems and thus did QA using it, until it was replaced with full disk encryption*). You were void of specifics; Ubuntu Server offers one installer option currently; Ubuntu Desktop offers two ISOs for download that use different installers; use whatever works for you.  *generic answer is yes you can do what you're asking; done appropriately*

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Then I will clone my whole home folder into an external disk and copy back after formatting and full-disk encryption completed.